# Specs2/Guice issue in Play 2.4.0 functional tests

Tags: scala, playframework, guice, specs2, playframework-2.4

I'm having an issue with dependencies apparently bleeding between tests, which is causing most of the tests to fail. In each case, debugging shows the first app created in a test class is used for all tests, and this is resulting in the failures.

I've tried adding `isolated` and `sequential` and this has had no effect.

Am I doing something remarkably stupid or subtly stupid?

For example, here's [SubjectNotPresentTest.scala](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala/blob/master/code/test/be/objectify/deadbolt/scala/views/subjectTest/SubjectNotPresentTest.scala)

```
class SubjectNotPresentTest extends AbstractViewTest {

  "show constrained content when subject is not present" in new WithApplication(testApp(handler())) {
    val html = subjectNotPresentContent(FakeRequest())

    private val content: String = Helpers.contentAsString(html)
    content must contain("This is before the constraint.")
    content must contain("This is protected by the constraint.")
    content must contain("This is after the constraint.")
  }

  "hide constrained content when subject is present" in new WithApplication(testApp(handler(subject = Some(user())))) {
    val user = new User("foo", Scala.asJava(List.empty), Scala.asJava(List.empty))
    val html = subjectNotPresentContent(FakeRequest())

    private val content: String = Helpers.contentAsString(html)
    content must contain("This is before the constraint.")
    content must not contain("This is protected by the constraint.")
    content must contain("This is after the constraint.")
  }
}
```

GuiceApplicationBuilder is used in a [parent class](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala/blob/master/code/test/be/objectify/deadbolt/scala/views/AbstractViewTest.scala) is used to create the app for testing.

```
val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
          .bindings(new DeadboltModule())
          .bindings(bind[HandlerCache].toInstance(LightweightHandlerCache(handler)))
          .overrides(bind[CacheApi].to[FakeCache])
          .in(Mode.Test)
          .build()
```

You can see an example of the failures at https://travis-ci.org/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala/builds/66369307#L805

All tests can be found at https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala/tree/master/code/test/be/objectify/deadbolt/scala/views

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is caused when the current Play application is statically referenced in a test environment in which there are multiple applications - even if they are logically separate.

Because components can't be injected (to the best of my knowledge) into templates, I created a [helper object](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala/blob/master/code/app/be/objectify/deadbolt/scala/ViewAccessPoint.scala#L13-L14) which uses `Play.current.injector` to define a couple of `val`s.

```
  val viewSupport: ViewSupport = Play.current.injector.instanceOf[ViewSupport]
  val handlers: HandlerCache = Play.current.injector.instanceOf[HandlerCache]
```

(It's also not possible, TTBOMK, to inject into objects, otherwise I could just inject the components into the object and everyone could go home).

A better approach is to expose what is required as an implicit.

```
object ViewAccessPoint {

    private[deadbolt] val viewStuff = Application.instanceCache[ViewSupport]
    private[deadbolt] val handlerStuff = Application.instanceCache[HandlerCache]

    object Implicits {
        implicit def viewSupport(implicit application: Application): ViewSupport = viewStuff(application)
        implicit def handlerCache(implicit application: Application): HandlerCache = handlerStuff(application)
    }
}
```

In the view, import the implicits and you're good to go.

```
@import be.objectify.deadbolt.scala.DeadboltHandler
@import be.objectify.deadbolt.scala.ViewAccessPoint.Implicits._
@import play.api.Play.current
@(handler: DeadboltHandler = handlerCache(current).apply(), name: String, meta: String = null, timeout: Function0[Long] = viewSupport.defaultTimeout)(body: => play.twirl.api.Html)(implicit request: Request[Any])

@if(viewSupport.dynamic(name, meta, handler, timeout(), request)) {
@body
}
```